# nginx Windows: setting up sites-available configs

Tags: windows, nginx

I'm trying to set up Nginx on my Windows development environment. I can't find how to create something similar to `"sites-enabled"` on Linux where Nginx would look for (links to) active virtual host configurations.

Is there a way to do something similar with a directory with shortcuts to the actual configuration files and Nginx scanning that directory? Or is there another way to hook up a virtual host configuration other than copying the host configuration to `nginx.conf`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The "sites-enabled" approach as used by some Linux packages of nginx utilize `include` directive, which understands shell wildcards, see http://nginx.org/r/include.  You may use it in your own config as well, e.g.

```
http {
    ...
    include /path/to/sites/*.conf;
}
```

Note though that such approach might be very confusing (in particular, it would be hard to tell which server{} is the default one unless you use `default_server` explicitly).

Comment: None of these work for me: `include f:\code\mysite\dev-ops\nginx\dev\mysite.conf;` 
`include "f:\code\mysite\dev-ops\nginx\dev\mysite.conf";` 
`include f:/code/mysite/dev-ops/nginx/dev/mysite.conf;`

Comment: @Ryan escape your backslashes.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I am trying to include a custom config like:                                                         include "C:\\nginx-1.19.6\\conf\\conf.d\\*.conf";                                                                                        
But its not working

Answer (score 39):

In windows you have to give full path of the directory where the config files are located. There are two files to update: nginx.conf, which tells nginx where to find web sites, and localhost.conf, which is the configuration for a web site.

It is assumed that nginx is installed in `C:\nginx`. If the installation directory is at another path, you will have to update that path accordingly, wherever it appears in the following two configuration files.

## nginx.conf

Location: `C:\nginx\conf`

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    #to read external configuration.
    include "C:/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/*.conf";
}
```

## localhost.conf

Location: `C:\nginx\conf\sites-enabled`

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

Comment: Mind you, guys, wildcards do work only with forward slashes - `/`, *not* backward ones `\`, while regular paths work with both.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me but only AFTER I moved my main nginx exe folder from `c:/Program Files (x86)/nginx-1.7.0` to `c:/nginx-1.7.0` (because I think it doesn't handle spaces in file paths well):

```
http {
    ...
    include "f:/code/mysite/dev-ops/nginx/dev/mysite.conf";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Till the time of writing this answer (**7 Jan 2022**) non of the other answers fully answer this question.*
Wildcards (`include a/*.b`) just include a list of vhosts which cannot be disabled/enabled. **sites-enabled** and **sites-available** is about being able to disable a vhost without deleting the corresponding config file.
Nginx has only one config file (nginx.conf), which in turn includes other files. The ability to include files is what led to **enabled/available** design.
So the directory structure goes as follows:

```
conf // or whatever
|__nginx.conf
|__sites-enabled
|____default // symlink to sites-available/default.conf
|__sites-available
|____default.conf // You can omit the extension but I just like it
|____whatever.conf
|____some vhost.conf
|____another vhost.conf
|____disabled vhost.conf
|____other config files ...
```

```
# nginx.conf
http {
  # ...
  include path/to/sites-enabled/*; # include the enabled ones
}
```

In windows (cmd) you do:

```sh
mklink Link Target
# for example
mklink default X:/path/to/nginx/conf/sites-available/default.conf
```

*Many think that windows doesn't have symlinks, it does :-)*

I use a slightly more complex config directory structure, for development:

```
conf/
|__nginx.conf
|__sites-enabled/
|____some-site // sites-available/some-site/{env} where {env} is either dev or prod
|__sites-available/
|____some-site/
|______prod.conf
|______dev.conf
|______dev/
|________www.conf // vhost (server {}) for the www subdomain
|________api.conf // same as above but for the api subdomain
|________root.conf // vhost for the top level domain (e.g example.com without any subdomain prefix)
|______prod/
|________www.conf
|________api.conf
|________root.conf
|______snippets/
|________http.conf  // listen on ipv4 80/ipv6 80 and redirect http to https
|________https.conf // listen on ipv4 443 ssl/ipv6 443 ssl and `include`s ssl.conf
|________ssl.conf  // ssl config, pay attention to permission
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include your config with a relative path in your nginx.config (the relative path is just the path of the config file itself in contrast to the logs path for example):

```
http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  include       ../sites-enabled/*.conf;
  ...
}
```