# Spring Boot with Embedded Undertow behind AWS ELB - HTTP to HTTPS redirect

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, undertow

I'm running a Spring boot (Jhipster/Undertow) application on port 8080 on an AWS EC2 instance.

I have an AWS ELB configured to redirect

```
 80 -> 8080
 443 (SSL termination happens here) -> 8080
```

The application uses Spring Security and if you user arrives to http://example.com I want it to redirect to https://example.com, to use SSL.

I have found various examples of configuring this in [Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229352/spring-boot-with-embedded-tomcat-behind-aws-elb-https-redirect) but none using Undertow.

I have tried this, with a second port 8089, and it does redirect as required, but this causes port 8080 to also redirects which I don't want.

```
80 -> 8089
443 (SSL termination happens here) -> 8080
```

```java
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory undertow() {

    UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory undertow = new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    undertow.addBuilderCustomizers(builder -> builder.addHttpListener(8089, "0.0.0.0"));
    undertow.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(deploymentInfo -> {
        deploymentInfo.addSecurityConstraint(new SecurityConstraint()
                .addWebResourceCollection(new WebResourceCollection()
                        .addUrlPattern("/*"))
                .setTransportGuaranteeType(TransportGuaranteeType.CONFIDENTIAL)
                .setEmptyRoleSemantic(SecurityInfo.EmptyRoleSemantic.PERMIT))
                .setConfidentialPortManager(exchange -> 443);
    });
    return undertow;
}
```

How can I configure Undertow to achieve this?

Comment: does https://twitter.com/ankinson/status/829256167700492288 maybe relate to a similar problem, you want to solve?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when I had the same problem:

Expose the port 80 from jhipster (you can change it in the `application-prod.yml`).

Amazon ELB when redirecting from http to https adds some headers, which you should address in the same file:

`server:
    use-forward-headers: true
    port: 80`

Also, you need to enforce the https from jhipster:
https://jhipster.github.io/tips/007_tips_enforce_https.html

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if somebody wants a working solution for redirecting all **http** requests to **https** with **HTTP/2** in Spring Boot 1.5.19, following is the setting in `application.properties` file:

```
server.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=xxxxxxx
server.port=443
server.use-forward-headers=true
```

And the following Java configuration:

```java
import io.undertow.UndertowOptions;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.SecurityConstraint;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.SecurityInfo;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.TransportGuaranteeType;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.WebResourceCollection;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;


@Configuration
public class ConnectorConfig {

    @Bean
    public UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();

        factory.addBuilderCustomizers((UndertowBuilderCustomizer) builder -> {
            builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ENABLE_HTTP2, true);
            builder.addHttpListener(80, "0.0.0.0");
        });

        factory.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(deploymentInfo -> {
            deploymentInfo.addSecurityConstraint(
                    new SecurityConstraint()
                            .addWebResourceCollection(new WebResourceCollection().addUrlPattern("/*"))
                            .setTransportGuaranteeType(TransportGuaranteeType.CONFIDENTIAL)
                            .setEmptyRoleSemantic(SecurityInfo.EmptyRoleSemantic.PERMIT))
                    .setConfidentialPortManager(exchange -> 443);
        });

        return factory;
    }
}
```

Everything will be working perfectly.