# Undertow http and https

Tags: spring-boot, undertow

I use embedded undertow server in my web project. It works well in Idea with listening port 80 and 443, following the log in idea.

```
2018-08-04 11:32:31.394  INFO 4933 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.u.UndertowServletWebServer     : Undertow started on port(s) 443 (https) 80 (http) with context path ''
```

But when I run it on my ubuntu server or local command line:

```
java -jar xxxx.jar
```

Output log is

```
Undertow started on port(s) 443 (https) with context path ''
```

wihout listening port 80. I can only visit the site by inputing https://xxxx
handly.
I compared the log. The server log print the extra two lines

```
2018-08-04 11:38:37.950  WARN 14835 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026009: XNIO worker was not set      on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default worker will be used
2018-08-04 11:38:37.950  WARN 14835 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
```

I din't know what's wrong. Any answer is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide the configuration file here on redirecting http to https

Comment: @Samim Thanks~ Here is the code [link](https://github.com/TreeLiked/darkme2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/treeliked/darkme2/Darkme2Application.java) .

Comment: the link shows the configuration for Tomcat but I wanted the config for Undertow. However, I managed to do that. You can view it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908727/7538821

Comment: @Samim I am sorry to post the wrong code, I have solved the problem according to the link you provided, thank you